# can not invoke web service from websphere portal

Tags: web-services, websphere, axis

I am facing a problem related to axis.jar classes.

I have a WAR file that has axis.jar in its lib directory.
this WAR deployed on IBM websphere environment1 and this WAR is working fine.

when I deploy the same WAR in IBM websphere environment2 not working.

I got the following exception when I try to invoke a webservice:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryDefault

I have no idea why this class not loaded in environment2.

Note that the same WAR woking fine on environment1 and not working on environment2.

Any help please??

Comment: Do the two environments have all the same fix packs and feature packs installed?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Websphere classloader configuration.

I've faced these errors before, and they happen when you mix your version of axis, with missing dependencies, that are taken from Websphere. Usually, these Websphere dependencies are  outdated, and some classes/methods don't exist.

Provide axis.jar and its dependencies on the WEB-INF/lib folder, and configure classloading to PARENT_LAST.

Also be sure that your MANIFEST.MF is referencing axis libraries as well

This should do the work

Comment: I checked out and its loading the application classes first.

Comment: You should check the fixPack level on both servers. If they are the same version, should behave the same way, and fixpacks always seem to fix webservice related issues.